# Is it possible to convert Token from request string to Header in jwt authentication?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, request-headers

I'm using Tymon\JWTAuth with laravel 
and I'm sending the requests like this

```
 www.example.com/test?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjUzNywiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvbG9jYWxob3N0Ojg4ODhcL3YyXC9zZWxmXC9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUiLCJpYXQiOjE0NzE0MzI0ODMsImV4cCI6MTQ3MTQ3NTY4MywibmJmIjoxNDcxNDMyNDgzLCJqdGkiOiI4ZDVlZGE4MmE2MTZlMzM5NjgwMmFmZTk5NWI3N2Q1MCJ9.-t0El5nJj_pgNzpgtLy8EVLUsf9dp8RTLhWA3cK_Vmw
```

I want to move this token to header is that possible ?

Comment: If the requests are made from a client you must change the client side code not the server side unless you are doing a request from your backend to another service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can send the token with header.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication):

> To make authenticated requests via http using the built in methods, you will need to set an authorization header as follows:
>
> Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}